# Error when opening PhantomJS generated PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader DS

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

I am generating a PDF using PhantomJS, and it opens fine with Macs built in Preview, Google Docs, and a few other tools that I tested it on. However, when I open it using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 15.010.20056, I receive one of the most unhelpful messages of all time.

[image]

After this, my PDF is only partially generated. This happens both on PCs and Macs. I have no idea how to debug this or even start to figure out the cause.

Comment: If you wish to provide a bug report, you can do this [on GitHub](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues).

Comment: I was more looking for confirmation that this is in fact a bug and not some known error that could somehow be resolved via the user and not the product team.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm unsure of whether this is an Acrobat bug or PhantomJS bug...

Comment: Either way, if this is related to code, then you need to show the code that produces this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, PhantomJS doesn't properly render Tiling Patterns, setting up offsets X and Y offsets to be 0, which is actually not proper PDF specifications. This is one of the many reasons that PhantomJS renders things differently depending on how you open the generated PDF.